# Visual Studio Code でMarkdownプレビューを右側に表示する方法

Tags: vscode, markdown

以前 VSCode で Markdown ファイルを編集するとき、自動でウィンドウが左右分割され、右側にプレビューが表示されていた気がするのですが、現在はそのような挙動になりません。

仕方ないので「エディターの分割 (Ctrl+¥)」→「プレビューを開く (Ctrl+Shift+V)」→プレビューじゃないエディタが右パネルに残っているので閉じる、という操作を毎回行っているのですが、これを一回の操作で（願わくばファイルを開いたり言語を指定したら自動で）やりたいのですが、そういった設定などないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Auto-Open Markdown Preview - Visual Studio Marketplace
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hnw.vscode-auto-open-markdown-preview
この拡張機能で「自動でその右隣にプレビュータブを並べて表示」が実現できそうです。

Answer (score 2):

質問当時そんな状況があったかもしれませんが, (現在)以下の環境では <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> で表示可能です

(環境)

> バージョン: 1.54.1
> 〜
> Electron: 11.3.0
> Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
> Node.js: 12.18.3
> V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
> OS: Linux x64 5.8.0-44-generic